# Read and write binary file with reinterpreter_cast

Tags: c++, file, binary, reinterpret-cast

For example if i have a class named `Obj` and an `Obj` named `obj1`. When I want to write in a binary file with `reinterpret_cast` I open that file in binary mode and then,

```
outstream.write( reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&obj1), sizeof(obj1) )
```

where outstream is a ifstream.

When i want to read from that file,

```
instream.read( reinterpret_cast<char *>(&obj1), sizeof(obj1) )
```

What happened. It read the representation of `obj1` in binary and convert to `obj1` or how this is working. When I write I understand that it interpret `obj1` an one byte but when I read I don't understand what happens.

Comment: Doing this is not working properly for complex objects. You should lookup for de-/serialization.

Comment: Unless `Ob` is a POD type, this is undefined behavior.  Use `static_assert(std::is_pod<Obj>::value, "not POD");` to make this sure.

Comment: i dont understand how it decode the information when it read. How can i understand in the read what happens behind scene

Comment: Nothing happens behind the scene, that's exactly the point of `reinterpret_cast`! It seems you need to read up on *pointers* and different types of casts.

Comment: As we've said, for non-POD types, there is undefined behavior going on behind the scenes.  And for POD types, it is just as if you `memcpy` the bits of the object to / from the file.

Comment: I see this done in C++ How to program Fifth edition and they dont say anything like you. I do this for random acces file

Comment: I don't know that book so I don't want to judge it but maybe it is not a coincidence that it is not on [the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, an object of class `Obj` takes up 4 bytes in memory.

```
[OBJ] = [0][1][2][3]
      = FF FF FF FF  //(for example, all bytes contain 0xFF)
```

A `char`, normally, takes up 1 byte. So when you do the `reinterpret_cast` your object will be *treated* as the 4 separate bytes (an array of characters, so to speak).

When you serialize your object in this way you will store the raw bytes `0` through `3`, and your file will contain the `4` bytes `0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF`. Bottom line you're copying the raw bytes into a file.

Deserialization is just as simple, you have a placeholder Obj to be read into and then the same bytes in the file will overwrite the object.

---

There's a caveat. This sort of serialization will only work on POD types or structures with simple data members. Like this,

```
struct Foo {
    int bar1;
    float bar2;
};
```

It won't work on things like `std::vector`, or `std::list`, etc.
In general it won't work on pointers, because if you store the raw value (address) the pointer contains it will be meaningless in the next time you run your program and read this address. Your object will contain an invalid pointer after deserializing.

Comment: and if the obj is pod then in the read it uses the same "conversion" of the char bytes to convert to obj1 as it uses in the write to convert obj1 to char?

Comment: There was never any conversion, which is why I said _treated_. A reinterpret cast will not convert you data. Data (bytes) is the same no matter the type you're dealing with, what changes is the way the compiler uses this data. When you reinterpret_cast something, you tell the compiler to deal with this data as if it were something else, but there is no conversion.

Comment: ok now i start to understand what you said.So i understand that instead of char would be any base type and the result will be this?

Comment: If you mean that you could use any type and reinterpret cast it to char, well I mentioned that in my answer. If you mean that you could reinterpret cast to any other type besides char, you can do that too but you're at your own risk. Don't do it unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

When you re-interpret a pointer to object as a pointer to `char`, you write the in-memory representation of the object itself. This includes

- All pointers inside the object. For classes with virtual members this may include a pointer to vtable, depending on the implementation
- All padding between members,
- All data members, in the endianness of your hardware.

This write does not include any part of your object pointed to by pointers.

Moreover, when you read an object with pointers back into memory, the values in these pointers will be garbage. If you dereference any of it, you get undefined behavior.

This makes the technique applicable only to plain old data (POD) objects, i.e. primitives and structs/classes composed of primitives and other POD objects. In addition, the technique is not applicable when you need cross-hardware compatibility.